# A limit problem involving repeated cosines

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I was playing around on my calculator and I found something interesting:-

Let's say I take some value $x$ in degrees and apply the following operation: $cos(cos(cos(cos....(x)))))...)$. This always seems to converge to the value $0.999847741531...$, regardless of $x$. It doesn't seem to happen for the $sin$ or $tan$ functions though.

How do I prove that the "limit" of this repeated "$cos$ operation" is the above value (it seems to be an irrational number)? (Assuming that it does converge to that value, of course. I'm not sure if it does though.)

I tried the following:-

Let $y = cos(cos(.....(x))))...)$, where the operation is applied an infinite number of times (Sorry, but I do not know how to express this in a better notation), and where $x$ can take any real value in degrees.

So, $y$ can be expressed as $y=cos(y)$, i.e. $y - cos(y) = 0$. How do I solve this equation for $y$, while also proving that it has only a unique solution, and that the solution is the above-mentioned value?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle is in degrees, yes?

It is easy to show that the answer is unique. cos(y) is always between -1 and 1, so any solutions must be in this range. cos(y) is always positive in this range, so any solutions have to be in the range 0 to 1. And in this range, y=cos(x) decreases while y=x increases, so they only cross at one point.

A good way to compute the solution to high precision is by the Newton Raphson method. I don't think there is a nice formula for it.

If you only want a few digits (15 or so) then just pressing the "cos" button repeatedly is also a good method of computing the solution. The error decreases by a factor of about 0.017 with every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

To first prove that there is a solution to the equation $y-\cos(y)=0$ we can use the [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem). Let $f(y)=y-\cos(y)$. Then $f$ is continuous, $$f(0)=-1<0$$ and $$f\left(\frac\pi 2\right)=\frac\pi 2>0,$$ so there exists some $y_0\in (0,\frac \pi 2)$ such that $f(y_0)=0$.

To show that there is a unique such solution, first we observe that the only possible solutions must be in $[-1,1]$ since this is the range of $\cos$. The derivative of $f$ is
$$f'(y) = 1 - \sin(y)$$ which is positive on $[-1,1]$, hence $f$ is strictly increasing on $[-1,1]$. In particular, it reaches the value $0$ only once.

As for computing the exact value, I don't think there is a nice formula for $y_0$. You could use [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to approximate it.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the solution is unique, you can just take the derivative of $x-\cos (\frac {\pi x}{180})$ and observe that it is always positive.  You can plot it in [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x-cos%28x%2api/180%29%20from%20-1%20to%202) and see it isn't close.

To get the value, you need a one-dimensional root finder.  They are discussed in any numerical analysis text.  Again, [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20x=cos%28x%2api/180%29) will solve it for you, giving as many decimals as you want.